# how to call a statement block in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

When write a stored procedure, there maybe is a duplicate code for same situation, for example, error processing. In order reuse the code, a function can be created and call this function.

Is it possible to have a statement block inside the stored procedure and can be call many times without to create a function?

Comment: If you use a try catch block, you only need to write the error processing once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GOTO statements, but please don't.  The pros of creating a function and using it far outweigh the cons, in my opinion.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180188.aspx